# Mutex doesn't appear to release even after I release it

Tags: c#, .net

I have a number of services that read xml files. To make sure that there is no collisions I use a mutex. For whatever reason, if all of my services are run by the same user there is no problem. However, if there are different users running these services, even after one service has released the mutex, the other gets the following exception when calling enter route mutex "Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'createMutex.Program' threw an exception. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'RETEST_MUTEX' is denied."

```
    public static readonly String ROUTE_MUTEX_STRING = "RETEST_MUTEX";
    private static Mutex _routeMutex = new Mutex(false, ROUTE_MUTEX_STRING);

    /// <summary>
    /// Thin wrapper around the static routeMutex WaitOne method
    /// Always call ExitRouteMutex when done in protected area
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="millis_timeout"></param>
    /// <returns>true if signaled, like WaitOne</returns>
    public static bool EnterRouteMutex(int millis_timeout)
    {
        try
        {
            return _routeMutex.WaitOne(millis_timeout, false);
        }
        catch (AbandonedMutexException ame)
        {
            // swallow this exception - don't want to depend on other apps being healthy - like pre .NET 2.0 behavior
            // data integrity will be checked
            return _routeMutex.WaitOne(millis_timeout, false);
        }

    }

    public static void ExitRouteMutex()
    {
        try
        {
            _routeMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        catch (ApplicationException)
        {
            // swallow, reduce complexity to client
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        bool get = EnterRouteMutex(1000);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Mutex created Press enter " + get.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();            
        ExitRouteMutex();
        Console.WriteLine("Mutex Release");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Press enter");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: You probably need to use the constructor form that accepts a `MutexSecurity` object, and supply it with an object that permits all accesses to the mutex.

Comment: Don't you need to use Mutex.OpenExisting() if it's already created in another process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of doing a cross-process Mutex.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c41ybyt3.aspx

It handles the use of Mutex.OpenExisting and also demonstrates the security aspect mentioned by cdhowie.